# Не создается соединение WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

В попытке создать чат для сайта наткнулся на решение через WebSocket, с описанием событий проблем не возникло. Но само соединение не создается, я использую OpenServer, может дело в этом?
Получаю ошибку, возможно проблема с выбором порта. Заранее большое спасибо

```
    Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://shop.local:8081/orders.php
```

Вот сам код

```
 const socket = new WebSocket("ws://shop.local:8081/orders.php");
socket.onerror = function(e) {
    let problems = document.createElement("div");
    let buttons = document.getElementById('right-buttons');
    problems.className = "problems";
    problems.innerHTML = "<div>Проблемы с соединением</div><img src='/img/gif/giphy.gif'>";
    buttons.append(problems);
    }
socket.onclose= function(e) {
    let problems = document.createElement("div");
    let buttons = document.getElementById('right-buttons');
    problems.className = "problems";
    problems.innerHTML = "<div>Соединение закрыто</div>";
    buttons.append(problems);
    }
```

Comment: А покажите, как вы поднимаете websocket на сервере?

Comment: Не очень понимаю как это сделать. Для этого надо написать серверную часть на php? Выполняю все последовательно по гайдам с ютуба. Хотите сказать ошибка вызвано, тем что не описана работа сокета на сервере? Думаю вы правы, я не подумал об этом сразу

Comment: Гм, а с кем должен ваш вебсокет общаться? Для диалога нужны как минимум двое. Откуда должны данные приходить? Конечно, нужна серверная часть!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Предполагал, что ошибка вызваны js кодом, а это многое объясняет